# Constant expression from the choice of overloaded function?

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, overloading

Considering the following example (I posted it for several different questions today) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

// Version A
template<typename T>
constexpr unsigned int f(const T&)
{
    return 1;
}

// Version B
template<typename... T1, template<typename...> class T>
constexpr unsigned int f(const T<T1...>&)
{
    return 2;
}

// Version C
template<typename T1, template<typename, unsigned int...> class T, unsigned int... N>
constexpr unsigned int f(const T<T1, N...>&)
{
    return 3;
}

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::integral_constant<int, f(double())> a;
    std::integral_constant<int, f(std::vector<double>())> b;
    std::integral_constant<int, f(std::array<double, 3>())> c;
    std::cout<<a<<b<<c<<std::endl; // The goal is to return 123
    return 0;
}
```

This code does not compile and returns the following compilation error :

```
temporary of non-literal type 'std::vector<double>' in a constant expression
```

How to modify this code in order to compile it ?

Note : the goal is to convert a type that will be taken by the first version of the function to 1, a type that will be taken by the second version of the function to 2, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use temporary vector when defining constant:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::integral_constant<int, f(double())> a;
    std::vector<double> vec;
    std::integral_constant<int, f(vec)> b;
    std::integral_constant<int, f(std::array<double, 3>())> c;

    std::cout << a << b << c;
    return 0;
}
```

The thing is that compiler could possibly omit `vector` creation, if vector's only purpose was passing to the constant expression function, but actually it cannot, because vector is not literal type.

`std::array` is only a thing wrapper above c array, it has trivial constructor and destructor. As double is also literal type, array of doubles becomes literal.

Note, however, that if you define

```
struct A
{
    A(){std::cout << "I'm so complicated A!\n"; }
}
```

you would not be able to use constructs:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::integral_constant<int, f(A())> a;
    std::integral_constant<int, f(std::array<A, 3>())> c;

    std::cout << a << b << c;
    return 0;
}
```

either, while

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A a_v;
    std::integral_constant<int, f(a_v)> a;

    std::array<A, 3> c_v
    std::integral_constant<int, f(c_v)> c;

    std::cout << a << b << c;
    return 0;
}
```

still would be possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need partial specialization wich is impossible on functions, wrapping them in a struct/class gets the job done :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

// Version A                                                                                                                                                   
template<typename T>
struct f
{
  constexpr static unsigned int execute()                                                                                                                      
  {                                                                                                                                                            
    return 1;                                                                                                                                                  
  }
};

// Version B                                                                                                                                                   
template<template <typename ... > class Tpl, typename ... TplArgs>
struct f< Tpl<TplArgs...> >
{
  constexpr static unsigned int execute()                                                                                                                      
  {                                                                                                                                                            
    return 2;                                                                                                                                                  
  }
};

// Version C                                                                                                                                                   
template<template<typename, std::size_t...> class Tpl, typename FirstArg, std::size_t... N>
struct f< Tpl<FirstArg, N...> >
{
  constexpr static unsigned int execute()                                                                                                                      
  {                                                                                                                                                            
    return 3;                                                                                                                                                  
  }
};

// Main                                                                                                                                                        
int main(int argc, char* argv[])                                                                                                                               
{                                                                                                                                                              
  std::integral_constant<int, f<double>::execute()> a;                                                                                                         
  std::integral_constant<int, f<std::vector<double>>::execute()> b;                                                                                            
  std::integral_constant<int, f<std::array<double, 3>>::execute()> c;                                                                                          

  std::cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question to you is how much can we afford to modify this code? For instance, the following compiles, but is it what you were trying to do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

// Version A
template<typename T>
constexpr unsigned int f()
{
    return 1;
}

// Version B
template<typename... T1, template<typename...> class T>
constexpr unsigned int f()
{
    return 2;
}

// Version C
template<typename T1 = double, template<typename, unsigned int...> class T, unsigned int... N>
constexpr unsigned int f()
{
    return 3;
}

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::integral_constant<int, f<double>()> a;
    std::integral_constant<int, f<std::vector<double>>()> b;
    std::integral_constant<int, f<std::array<double, 3>>()> c;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using pointers instead of references :

```
// Version A
template<typename T>
constexpr unsigned int f(const T*)
{
    return 1;
}

// Version B
template<typename... T1, template<typename...> class T>
constexpr unsigned int f(const T<T1...>*)
{
    return 2;
}

// Version C
template<typename T1, template<typename, unsigned int...> class T, unsigned int... N>
constexpr unsigned int f(const T<T1, N...>*)
{
    return 3;
}

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<double> tmp;
    std::integral_constant<int, f(static_cast<double*>(nullptr))> a;
    std::integral_constant<int, f(static_cast<decltype(tmp)*>(nullptr))> b;
    std::integral_constant<int, f(static_cast<std::array<double, 3>*>(nullptr)) > c;
    std::cout<<a<<b<<c<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe it's not the most elegant way to do it but it works. If someone has an elegant equivalent of this, I am very interested in.

Comment: Look at my answer, would that be more elegant to you ? :)